# How does the number density of supernovae change with red shift

Tags: supernova, redshift

I am interested to know more about how the number of supernovae found changes according to their distance/red shift.

I have heard but I can't remember where that the number of supernovae is greater at higher red shifts.  I would like to confirm if this is true and also to understand why this is the case.  Thanks.

Comment: You conjecture or recollection may be correct. As time progresses the rate of stellar formation declines. This is probably accompanied by a decline the rate of supernovae with time.

Comment: Higher z typically means less metallic and therefore, larger and hotter stars, which do not last as long as the converse.  So my naive guess would be that yes, there would be more supernovas at larger z.